# C programming , using alarm

Tags: c

I am trying to just work around different modification of program. 
I have a process and the parent gets killed after alarm signal goes on 
The child still runs an infinite loop, since the alarm is in main it does not get affected
The program does not terminate at all
I am trying to include kill signal so i can have the child killed after sometime as ctrl-c does not work

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){  
    alarm(4);   //alarm in 4 seconds and terminates the program 

    int pid=fork();    //forks a child
    //if we keep the kill signal here it creates child kills it and goes to parent process
    while(1){
        if(pid==0)
            printf("I am the child \n");    //alarm clock does not effect the child process 
        else  //parent process 
            printf("I am the parent, child pid=%d\n", pid);  //this after alarm clock terminates the program
    // if we add "kill(pid, SIGKILL), doesnt even fork the child and kills it
        sleep(1);
        //kill(pid, SIGKILL); would run the child process and then kill it 
    }
}
```

Trying to get a little understanding on how can i kill child in this process after some time

Comment: How about programming the "child" in such a way that it dies by itself?

Comment: OT: the `fork()` function returns three(3) kinds of return value: <0 means an error occurred.  ==0 means in the child process  > 0 means in the parent process.  The code fails to check all three conditions

Answer (score 1):

Use a signal handler for your alarm. In that handler, `kill()` the child process and `wait()` for it to terminate.

For example:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t kill_pid = -1;
int done_flag = 0;

void handle_alarm(pid_t sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGALRM && kill_pid >= 0)
    {
        kill(kill_pid, SIGTERM);
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        done_flag = 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    alarm(4);   //alarm in 4 seconds and terminates the program

    pid_t pid = fork();    //forks a child
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            printf("I am the child \n");
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    else
    { //parent process
        kill_pid = pid;
        signal(SIGALRM, handle_alarm);

        while (!done_flag)
        {
            printf("I am the parent, child pid=%d\n", pid);
            sleep(1);
        }

        printf("Child has been terminated, parent is complete.\n");
    }
}
```

You could put a signal handler in the child process and make it terminate more gracefully. I've used `SIGTERM` here, which you can handle. `SIGKILL` cannot be handled by your program.

Comment: It can be seen as some sort of SW watchdog. It's very interesting.